# Multi-row row....row detail

Tags: ag-grid

Reviewing the ag grid here and I have a question about it.  Is it possible to have a multi-row logical row?  In other words a row that has cells corresponding to the defined columns, and then a second full length row with some detail, but have the whole thing act as a single row as far as hover effect, selection, sorting, etc?  Would this be possible without having to get deeply created with CSS rules to wipe out border lines and so forth?  I have looked at the master-detail, but I dont want the user to have to click on a down arrow to get it.  I just want it displayed as is.  No expanding or anything like that.  I am attaching a drawn mockup of what I am wanting to see if ag-grid can do this simply.

[image: mockup of proposed grid]

Comment: Did you look at ["Full Width Rows"](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/full-width-rows/)?

Comment: @thirtydot I did, but that doesnt incorporate in with a standard row, but it is an example of what I would like.  I would like a normal row with all the columns, and below that a full width row, but then have the both of them be a logical single row, where if you click on that row, both the standard row and full width row would select, if the column widths are changed, the standard row column widths would change, etc.

Comment: You can try setting your rows to have a fixed height of whatever, and then in cells for Name column, have your two lines of text (might need `cellRenderer`), and turn off `overflow: hidden` (for testing: `.ag-cell-value { overflow: visible !important; }`).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a Custom Detail section?

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail-custom-detail/

And then use css to remove the expand arrow if you really don't want to see it

In this example all the rows are expanded by default using onFirstDataRendered

https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&preview

```
onFirstDataRendered(params: FirstDataRenderedEvent) {
    // expand the first two rows
    setTimeout(function () {
      params.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
        node.setExpanded(true);
      });
    }, 0);
  }
```